# Hyperlegder fabric node Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed Unhandled error for request GET /api/fabric/1_0/channels:

Tags: arrays, node.js, go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

This is the issue while running the fabric-sdk-rest code:

```
"Peer {
  _options: 
   { 'grpc.ssl_target_name_override': 'peer0',
     'grpc.default_authority': 'peer0',
     'grpc.max_receive_message_length': -1,
     'grpc.max_send_message_length': -1 },
      clientCert: undefined,
      _url: 'grpc://0.0.0.0:7051',
      _endpoint: Endpoint { addr: '0.0.0.0:7051', creds: 
      ChannelCredentials {} },
     _name: '0.0.0.0:7051',
      _request_timeout: 45000,
     _grpc_wait_for_ready_timeout: 3000,
    _endorserClient: 
   ServiceClient {
     '$interceptors': [],
     '$interceptor_providers': [],
     '$channel': Channel {} },
  _discoveryClient: 
   ServiceClient {
     '$interceptors': [],
     '$interceptor_providers': [],
     '$channel': Channel {} } 
}
```

Error Log:

> [fabricconnector.js]: Failed to queryChannels: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed
>       Unhandled error for request GET /api/fabric/1_0/channels: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed
>           at Object.exports.createStatusError (/home/rev-mg/HyperledgerTest/fabric-sdk-rest/packages/loopback-connector-fabric/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
>           at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/rev-mg/HyperledgerTest/fabric-sdk-rest/packages/loopback-connector-fabric/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
>           at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/rev-mg/HyperledgerTest/fabric-sdk-rest/packages/loopback-connector-fabric/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:564:42)
>           at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/rev-mg/HyperledgerTest/fabric-sdk-rest/packages/loopback-connector-fabric/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:614:8)
>           at callback (/home/rev-mg/HyperledgerTest/fabric-sdk-rest/packages/loopback-connector-fabric/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:841:24)"

Comment: Same error here, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had same error message when client tried create insecure connection but server use ssl

If you use node.js try to replace

```
grpc.credentials.createInsecure()
```

with

```
grpc.credentials.createSsl()
```